# How to change a VM's checkpoint type from Production to Standard using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I need to change the checkpoint type from "Production" to "Standard" using powershell.

My current script for creating the new vm is pasted here, but that creates a VM with "Production" checkpoints.

```
param([String] $vmName, [String] $baseVMPath)

$vhdPath = $baseVMPath + "\" + $vmName + "\Virtual Hard Disks\" + $vmName + ".vhdx"

$switchName = "External switch for Hyper-V"

New-VM -Name $vmName -MemoryStartupBytes 8GB -Generation 2 -NewVHDPath $vhdPath -NewVHDSizeBytes 127GB -Path $baseVMPath -SwitchName $switchName

Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName $vmName –Path D:\Media\en_windows_10_enterprise_x64_dvd_6851151.iso

$dvd = Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName $vmName

Set-VMFirmware -VMName $vmName -FirstBootDevice $dvd

Set-VMMemory $vmName -DynamicMemoryEnabled $False

Start-VM –Name $vmName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the -CheckpointType flag on set-vm.